# Creating an image badge with Cocoa/OSX

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsimage, badge

I need to create an image badge in Cocoa.  Basically I need to take two images one smaller then the other and overlay the smaller image over the larger image with a certain offset.  Does Cocoa provide any utility to make this sort of thing easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a third image by compositing the two. It's pretty straight forward if you give the [drawing documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) a read. Particularly the [Images](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-BCIBBFGJ) section.